# Bootstrap tooltip only shows a second

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have an image that is an email icon and I want to display a tooltip when you click on the image. Here is an example of how it should be except it should be like this on my email icon image: [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/c1rogqxw/52/) and here is the code that I have: Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Help</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mai.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="group">
                <a href=""><img data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" title="contact@oxybin.travel" class="icons" alt="Email icon" onmouseover="this.src='Travel/email-color.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Travel/email.png'" src="Travel/email.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
html {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.icons {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I click on the image the tooltip only show up for less then a second and I want it to stay until you click elsewhere on the screen and then it should disappear. How can I solve this?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and make sure you link all required resources, including your images (or repalcers, with same size).

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/c1rogqxw/53/) works for me, what browser are you using?

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-info gly-radius" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="" data-content="Click any question mark icon to get help and tips with specific tasks" aria-describedby="tooltip">
  <span><img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/1674-200.png"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Click any question mark icon to get help and tips with specific tasks</span>
  <!-- Alert -->
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem was that I wrapped my image inside an a tag so whenever i clicked the image it would show the tooltip and update my page and that was the problem.